# Closing windows phone app programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am using the following code to check for network access in the start of my application

```
public async void CheckNetwork()
    {
        if (!NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            MessageDialog Message = new MessageDialog("Network access not available.", "Network Error");
            Message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Close"));
            await Message.ShowAsync();
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

This works as expected in Windows 10 desktop. But when I am running the app in my Phone, it fails to close the app. What could be the reason for this and how to force close my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a design principle, you are not supposed to manually close an app. Please refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn148258(v=vs.105).aspx) (adressed to WP8 developers, but is still valid). 
But, if you are working on a test app for yourself, you can throw an exception which is the only way possible to close the app.

```
throw new Exception();
```

Please don't do that if you aim to publish your app on the market :

> An unhandled exception in your app consumes resources unnecessarily both on the user’s phone and on the Windows Phone servers.
>   The phone generates and uploads crash dumps for unhandled exceptions to help you find and fix bugs in your code. Crashing your app to close it wastes the user’s battery power and network bandwidth.

Comment: My app needs network access to work. There are no functionalities without using network access. So I thought it doesn't make any sense to jut open the app when there is no network availability. That is why I want to close the app. What other options do I have?

Comment: I would say a special page explaining that no network was found, inviting the user to change his WiFi / data settings. You can insert in this page special links targetting the device settings (URIs "ms-settings:network-wifi" and "ms-settings:datausage"), please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228342.aspx to insert these links

Comment: As robin abishek says, use `Terminate` if you must exit the app.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I can't find the Terminate method. I changed my app to redirect to settings page when there is not Network access as bviale suggested.

Comment: Oops, `Terminate` is for Silverlight apps, sorry. `Exit` should work unless there's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

try Application.Current.Terminate() instead of Exit()

Comment: There is no Application.Current.Terminate() method. Am I missing any references?

Comment: @MohamedShakeel, It is there in the official documentation. Check this link..[https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.application.terminate(v=vs.105).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.application.terminate(v=vs.105).aspx).. You can check the version information there. It is supported by Windows Phone OS

Comment: @robinabishek thanks but it is for WinPhone8 & 8.1 ,not  Win10 & Win10Mobile

Comment: Those API's are for WinPhone 8.1 only i guess. You can check the official documentation for Win10 API's

Answer (score 1):

Try execute `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()`.